# why is the value of sum changing

Tags: c, loops, sum

i am new to c programming. The value of the code needs to be 0 after the loop but it changes. Please help someone.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
int n, i, k, j, sum;

char input[] = "";

scanf("%d", &n);

sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i< n; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", &input[i]);
    
    //sum = sum + (input[i]-48);
}

    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Declare all of your variables as close as possible to where they're used. That is `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of having a jumble of them up at the top.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `sum` is never changed.

Comment: `char input[] = "";` -- input is too short to hold the string. Most probably you are going out of bounds

Comment: your have some real problems there, you didnt allocate memory for `input[]` , and you go out of its boundary! this will encounters sigmentation fault !

Comment: @Adam, actually the compiler *will* allocate memory for `input[]`, But in his case only 1 `char`, which I agree, is probably not enough. Oh, and going out of bounds is undefined behavior and not will not automatically lead to segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an array but leave the size blank, it is sized to exactly fit what it is initialized with.

In this case you initialize it with an empty string which is 1 byte long (for the terminating null character) so the array is only 1 character wide.  So if you attempt to read any nonempty string into this variable you'll write past the bounds of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As a start, make the array at least as large as you expect the input to be, for example:

```
char input[80];
```

Then read the string once, limiting the input to the size of the array minus 1, *then* loop through the values:

```
scanf("%79s", input);
for (i = 0; i< n; i++)
{
    sum = sum + (input[i]-48);
}
```